# Initializing const value in c++ header with value returned by function

Tags: c++, header, constants

Is there any way to define conastant foo in c++ header "foo.hpp"

```
const int foo;
```

and initialize it with value returned by function bar defined in "bar.hpp"

```
int bar();
```

? (Either in foo.hpp or in foo.cpp.)

Comment: `#include "bar.hpp"` and then `const int foo = bar();`?

Comment: You mean `const int foo = bar();`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why not a `static const` member? Global/namespace variables can be used, but I prefer `static const` cus you don't have to worry about extern.

Comment: @mike-seymour Not really. When doing like this I get compilation error: error: initializer element is not constant

Comment: @jrok the same as above

Comment: @MadScienceDreams the same as above

Comment: @user2643716 The compiler is wrong, then. Unless you're actualy using a C compiler.

Comment: @user2643716: Are you sure this is C++, not C? C++ allows you to use any expression to initialise a global variable; but C only allows constant expressions, and GCC gives that exact error message.

Comment: @user2643716 `\*foo.hpp*\ class Foo { public: static const int foo; };  \*foo.cpp*\ int Foo::foo = bar();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

```
extern const int foo;
```

in *foo.hpp* and

```
const int foo = bar();
```

in *foo.cpp*.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is:

```
// foo.hpp
const int foo = bar();
```

as you can [see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ec72917a5548723) it works just fine.